# Cannot save a document in Mongoose - Validator required failed for path error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Following is my schema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
});
```

Now, when I attempt to save a document of the above schema, I get the following error:

```
{ message: 'Validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors: 
   { username: 
      { message: 'Validator "required" failed for path username',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        path: 'username',
        type: 'required' } } }
```

The above is the error object returned by mongoose upon save. I searched for this error but could not understand what is wrong. The document that I am trying to save is as follows:

```
{
username: "foo"
password: "bar"
}
```

Any idea what this means? I searched the mongoose docs too but could not find anything under the validation section.

Comment: Could you show the exact code you're using to create and save the document? (FWIW, the document misses a `,` at the end of the `username` line).

Answer (score 1):

First, you are missing a comma (,) after `foo`.

Now, is `{ username: "foo", password: "bar" }` JSON sent via http, our an actual object in your server-side code ?

If it is, try to `console.log(youVariable.username)` and see if it shows `undefined` or the value `foo`. If you see `undefined`, then your object is not parsed properly.

You can make sure that whom ever is sending the POST request is sending a "application/json" in the header, you could be receiving something else, thus your JSON isn't parsed to a valid javascript object.